# Cookies из xNet в HttpWebRequest c#

Tags: c#, cookie, xnet

Есть кукисы, которые сохранены в CookieDictionary (xNet), нужно их импортировать в гет запрос HttpWebRequest, делаю так :

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
            foreach (var cook in cookies.ToList()) //CookieDictionary cookies;
            {
                req.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cook.Key, cook.Value, "/","domen.ru"));
            }
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            return Out;
```

Но в строке   `req.CookieContainer.Add(...` выдает ошибку

> Необработанное исключение типа `"System.NullReferenceException"`
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр
>   объекта.

Можете помочь решить ?

Comment: Отладчик в руки и проверять, что там null. Хотя тут, похоже, уже в ответах угадали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так во всех примерах показано что нужно сперва создать/инициализировать куки контейнер..

```
httpRequest.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
```

Или

```
httpRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

Скорее всего Вы этот шаг упустили.